# How to make fixed position div inherit width of flex sized parent?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-position

I have a setup with two flexbox sized divs, inside of one I have a header that is set to position fixed. How would I make it so its width is 100% of the parent? It needs to stay inside the parent regardless of it's width. Thanks.

```css
.block1 {
  height: 102.5%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  flex-basis: 35%;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  position: relative;
  overflow: scroll;
  background-color: white;
  outline: solid red 1px;
}

.block2 {
  outline: solid red 1px;
  height: 102.5%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  flex-basis: 65%;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  position: relative;
  overflow: scroll;
  background-color: white;
}

.header {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: red;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 70%;
  display: flex;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  margin: 0px;
  outline: solid blue 1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="block1">
    <div style="height:200px;">
      <div class="header">ff</div>
      <div style="height:500px;">
        ff
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="block2">
    <div style="height:200px;">
      ff

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/nurqcq3e/

Comment: What you're trying to do won't work, you need to rethink your page structure.  fixed position elements are removed from their parent context when styling by design.  You need an outer container that dictates the width of both elements to achieve this.

Answer (score 4):

You need to create a new containing block for the `position: fixed` element. By default, using `position: fixed` pulls that element out of the document flow and positions it relative to the initial containing block established by the viewport (i.e., the `<body>`). [MDN has a great overview of this property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#fixed):

> The element is removed from the normal document flow, and no space is created for the element in the page layout. It is positioned relative to the initial containing block established by the viewport, except when one of its ancestors has a transform, perspective, or filter property set to something other than none (see the CSS Transforms Spec), in which case that ancestor behaves as the containing block. (Note that there are browser inconsistencies with perspective and filter contributing to containing block formation.) Its final position is determined by the values of top, right, bottom, and left.
>
> This value always creates a new stacking context. In printed documents, the element is placed in the same position on every page.

I went ahead and updated your code snippet to illustrate:

```css
.block1 {
  height: 102.5%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  flex-basis: 35%;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  position: relative;
  overflow: scroll;
  background-color: white;
  outline: solid red 1px;
  /* Necessary to become containing block for position: fixed child */
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

.block2 {
  outline: solid red 1px;
  height: 102.5%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  flex-basis: 65%;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  position: relative;
  overflow: scroll;
  background-color: white;
}

.header {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: red;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 70%;
  display: flex;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  margin: 0px;
  outline: solid blue 1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="block1">
    <div style="height:200px;">
      <div class="header">ff</div>
      <div style="height:500px;">
        ff
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="block2">
    <div style="height:200px;">
      ff

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I know It's been 2 years but I tried your solution and with `transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);`, the block is not "fixed" anymore and move along when I scroll...

Answer (score 0):

Try changing position from 'relative' to 'absolute' for a 'header' class.
If that does not help, can you provide some mock up?

Comment: can you explain a bit?

Answer (score 0):

### Dirty workarund

It's based on situation when fixed div contains text that expands it width.

If you add to .header div like below with long text it should do the job.

```
<div style="height: 0; overflow: hidden">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ...
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/6pwa7vxb/1/